# Alternative Html Helper Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is it possible to define a layout in code without using the Layout property.
The reason is that we want to generate a layout from a central company dll.
It needs to work will with sections (render section, generate section...)

Normally a layout is defined like this:

```
@{
    Layout = T4MVC.MVC.Shared.Views._Layout;
}
@section MySection{
 "custom section"
}
```

We would like to define the layout by calling a html helper.

```
@{
  @Html.RenderCompanyLayout()
}

@section MySection{
 "custom section"
}
```

Comment: You can use something like this var view = View(); view.masterName = "YourLayout"; return view; in controller, if you use this code , you wont need to specify Layout property in cshtml file

Comment: I want to use layout pages without having to define a separate layout.cshtml by calling a html helper.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you're trying to solve? In other words, why do you think you need this?

Comment: We have one big application with sub applications. These currently run together as one application with one application pool and shared layout pages. Now we need to migrate this currently existing architecture which is already in use for years. All sub applications need to become separate applications. The layout needs to be centrally defined so that with the release of one dll all applications (on different app pools) automatically use the latest layout without having to be updated and redeployed.

Comment: In the new architecture the old applications need to keep working together with new applications which will be 'Angular 4/AspNet core web api' based.

Comment: We don't want to have 30 applications with a copy of the layout(s). If an update needs to be done it needs to be done centrally.

Comment: Yes you can have a layout with a helper like "@Html.RenderCompanyLayout()". Have you tried doing it?

Comment: Yes I have tried this but I get into problems when using section. The system requires me to make a layout / view hierarchy with separate cshtml files. You need to define the section in a layout or view higher up in file hierarchy.